# What is the meaning of "...Type" in Go?

Tags: go

This code is in `builti.go`:

```
// The append built-in function appends elements to the end of a slice. If
// it has sufficient capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the
// new elements. If it does not, a new underlying array will be allocated.
// Append returns the updated slice. It is therefore necessary to store the
// result of append, often in the variable holding the slice itself:
//  slice = append(slice, elem1, elem2)
//  slice = append(slice, anotherSlice...)
// As a special case, it is legal to append a string to a byte slice, like this:
//  slice = append([]byte("hello "), "world"...)
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

The last line made me feel very confused. I do not know the meaning of `...Type` .

These are other codes:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   s := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
   s1 := s[:2]
   s2 := s[2:]
   s3 := append(s1, s2...)
   fmt.Println(s1, s2, s3)
}
```

The result is

```
[1 2] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5]
```

I guess the function of `...` is to pick all elements from `elems`, but I haven't found an official explanation. What is it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The code in builtin.go serves as documentation. The code is not compiled.

The `...` specifies that the final parameter of the function is variadic.  Variadic functions are [documented in the Go Language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters). In short, variadic functions can be called with any number of arguments for the final parameter.

The [Type](http://godoc.org/builtin#Type) part is a stand-in for any Go type.

Comment: And here's a great post about slices that could prove helpful: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks